# Request inside a loop and I get: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", does this have something to do with my request being inside a loop?

My code might help to understand the question:

```
    if (product.data.images.length > 0) {
      product.data.images.forEach(async (image: string) => {

        const body = {
          Url: imageURL + image,
        };
        call(code, image, body);
        
      });
    }
```

"call" function:

```
async function call(code: string, image: string, body: object) {
  const response = await api.patch(
    `/v1/Products(${code})/Images('${image}')`,
    body
  );
  res.status(201).json(response.data);
}
```

Complete error message:

Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

```
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)

at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)

at ServerResponse.header (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:776:10)

at ServerResponse.send (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)

at ServerResponse.json (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)

at /usr/app/src/modules/GoogleCron/imageController.ts:16:23

at step (/usr/app/src/modules/GoogleCron/imageController.ts:52:23)
```

[ERROR] 17:24:25 Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

```
at Object.next (/usr/app/src/modules/GoogleCron/imageController.ts:33:53)

at fulfilled (/usr/app/src/modules/GoogleCron/imageController.ts:24:58)

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by replacing the "res.status(201).json(response.data);" for "return response;". Is that a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The request being in the loop should be fine, but you can't have the response in the loop:

```
res.status(201).json(response.data);
```

This way you're attempting to send a response for each item in the loop.
You can only send one response.